# What is the best term in (global) copywriting: "sticky tape", "tape", "scotch tape" or "sellotape"?

Tags: generic-term, international

Perhaps "sticky tape" is childish? Sellotape is British?

It should be general and indicate the transparent, adhesive tape.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You can find useful reference here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Tape

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sticky+tape%2Cscotch+tape%2Ccellotape&case_insensitive=on

Comment: @Kris The ngrams are useless without interpretation. The fact that "Scotch tape" is the most common term indicates only that it's the most widely used term in one of the largest English-speaking communities (the USA). The question specifically asks about global understandability and, since "Scotch tape" is a trademark, it will only be understood where that particular product is widely known. I'm not sure if people in the UK know what "Scotch tape" is, for example (actually, the packaging shown on Wikipedia looks familiar so maybe it is sold here).

Comment: @DavidRicherby, to my UK understanding Scotch tape is slightly different to generic adhesive tape/Sellotape: Scotch tape a a roughened surface that can be written on with a ballpoint pen and looks translucent until applied when it appears transparent.  It's also easier to tear. According the the wikipedia article this is "Scotch magic tape"

Comment: Scotch Magic Brand Transparent Tape

Comment: "Scotch Magic" is a particular type of Scotch tape that is "frosty on the roll, invisible on the job", unlike the original Scotch "cellophane" tape which was shiny on the roll and still shiny after application.  "Magic" tape was first introduced in the US around 1960, I'm vaguely recalling.  Now that the "Magic" patent has no doubt expired most brands of household "cellophane tape" in the US have the same properties.

Comment: @HotLicks As another person in the UK, I can confirm the term "magic tape" is often used to refer to easy to use transparent tape. However I have never heard the term Scotch tape, and while it is for sale in some stationary stores it is not all that common.

Comment: @Vality - All my comments are from the standpoint of the US (where "Scotch tape" is the most common way to refer to transparent tape).

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed, I was not arguing with you, just trying to make the possibly interesting point that the "magic" term has stuck around heavily here to mean that despite the fact scotch tape is not too well known.

Comment: @Vality - Keep in mind that 3M (the Scotch folks) probably avoided using the "Scotch" brand in the UK, out of fear that it would be considered offensive/insensitive.  So they probably sold their tape under the "Magic" brand, without the "Scotch".

Comment: @DavidRicherby "I'm not sure if people in the UK know ..." -- no hurry, better make ourselves sure not only about UK but many other English-speaking countries.

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. The question asks for a term that's globally understood. If "Scotch tape" is not understood in the UK, that would already scotch it as a globally understood term. Saying "The UK does X" is not enough to prove that X is global but "The UK does not do X" (or "France does not do X" or "Japan does not do X") is enough to prove that X is not global.

Comment: @ChrisH Same here. "Sellotape" or "sticky tape" is, well, sticky tape and Scotch tape is the magic tape that comes off easily and has a sort of frosted appearance.

Answer (score 13):

*Adhesive tape* seems perfectly fine.

Both *Scotch tape* and *Sellotape* (not *cello*) are proprietary brand names (owned by 3M and Henkel) and may not be recognized in countries where the tape was either not marketed or not marketed under that brand name. 
It seems 3M marketed it as *Sticky Tape* in Australia.

If it is important that your audience understand that the tape is *transparent*, then simply call it, as you wrote, *transparent adhesive tape*. However, I suspect that for most people, *adhesive tape* is almost automatically assumed to be transparent unless you explicitly state the opposite.

As TRomano points out, U.S. audiences may indeed understand *adhesive tape* to be (non-transparent) masking tape, so your best bet is probably to include *transparent*.

Comment: [Adhesive tape](http://www.watershed-packaging.co.uk/images/maincontent/products/adhesive-tapes/adhesive-tapes-sizes.jpg) suggests to me that one side is plastic-coated in a solid colour. The image is taken from the first results on Google images.

Comment: But Adhesive tape is *clearly* the most popular term. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sticky+tape%2Cscotch+tape%2Ccellotape%2Csellotape%2Cadhesive+tape&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csticky%20tape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscotch%20tape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccellotape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csellotape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadhesive%20tape%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In the US "adhesive tape" has traditionally been reserved for tape to be used for bandaging wounds, etc, in particular the white cloth tape.  However, "transparent adhesive tape" would probably be understood to mean "Scotch tape".

Comment: And, as an aside, real "cellophane" largely disappeared from common use 30-40 years ago.  Cellophane is a particular type of clear flexible plastic which is not at all "stretchy" (making it a good base for the original "Scotch" tape).  For packaging, cellophane has largely been supplanted by other plastics, primarily polyethylene, that have more "stretch" and which can be thermally "welded".  I'm not sure what is currently used as the base for most transparent tapes, but it's not cellophane.  About the only place cellophane is still used is the "window" of boxes for bakery goods, etc.

Comment: The more common sticky tape these days is not transparent- it's translucent. "Clear" has the same problem. Using "translucent adhesive tape" or "translucent sticky tape" would probably work, but it rules out the clear variety for (perhaps) no good reason.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go with "sticky tape", or "clear sticky tape".  I don't think it' childish, and I think it's the generic name least likely to cause confusion.

Adhesive tape to me is a broad term that encompasses sticky tape, electrical tape, masking tape, duct tape, and perhaps some forms of medical tapes.

Try the different terms with google images and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I agree, and yet, I once had a USAn look at me cluelessly when I used the term. However, he was, to borrow his own phrase, a bit of a 'dumb ass'.

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to the term 'sticky tape' in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

*Cellophane tape* is a generic term for that kind of tape.

Comment: [Cellophane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane) is a distinctly different thing (also known as _cling film_). You mean _cellulose_ tape, and no, that is not, as far as I know, widely recognized to mean _adhesive tape_.

Comment: Not in the US. "Scotch [TM] brand tape is the best brand of cellophane tape".  It's the transparent adhesive tape you find in dispensers on office desks, utility tables, everywhere. Sticky on one side.

Comment: Then your answer is also not useful. The OP specifically asks about something that is globally recognized, and I can assure you that an American misunderstanding of _cellophane_ to mean _cellulose_ is _not_ globally recognized. Henkel called their adhesive tape _Sellotape_, for _cellulose tape_. Both adhesive tape and cling film are (or were) made from cellulose. I can assure you that _cellophane tape_ will be interpreted as _cling film tape_, whatever that is, by many people outside of the U.S.

Comment: In the US, "adhesive tape" might be confused with "masking tape" by some.  "Transparent adhesive tape" has probably the best chance of being universally understood.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google shows me roughly 5 times more results for "adhesive tape" than for "cellophane tape". I don't dispute that the expression is _locally_ recognized, but that was not the question :)

Comment: Good point about the U.S. interpretation as _masking tape_, thanks! :)

Comment: Italians call sticky tape *lo Scotch*, if that helps.

Comment: @Mari Probably not a good choice for English, though. “If the wound starts to reopen, apply copious amounts of Scotch” would probably give some very unintended results outside Italy. :-D

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's *plaster* in the UK, *cerotto* in Italian. And Italians do really believe that cellotape etc. is called *scotch* in anglophone countries.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, using actual adhesive tape would not be ideal there. I was just trying to come up some sort of reasonably believable situation where tape and whisky could ever be misunderstood… not too successfully.

Comment: @oerkelens even by the Wikipedia article you cited, you're wrong. "As well as packaging a variety of food items, there are also industrial applications, such as a base for such self-adhesive tapes as Sellotape and Scotch Tape". The article also specifically refutes that cellophane is a "distinctly different thing (also known as _cling film_)". Therefore "cellophane" in reference to tape is correct, and in reference to cling wrap is incorrect. To the topic at hand though, I would agree that not everyone would immediately understand what cellophane tape is -- as you have made evident :)

Comment: @DoktorJ: If Wikipedia tells me that both cellophane and Sellotape are made from cellulose, I have little reason to assume that means Sellotape is also based on cling film. I should have added _in my neck of the woods_ to the claim that they are distinctly different. I can assure you that around here, nobody expects cellophane to be anything else than cling film, but I was indeed incorrect to leave out the localisation :)

Comment: @oerkelens Cellophane has nothing whatsoever to do with clingfilm. Cellophane is a thin, crinkly, transparent plastic made from cellulose; cling film is an *extremely* thin, non-crinkly, transparent plastic made from polyethylene.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It seems to depend on who you ask. I can find plenty of suppliers that will sell me cellophane cling film. But I have to admit I was truly not aware that the word was interpreted and understood so differently on different sides of the pond. Something tells me I was not the only one though :)

Comment: @oerkelens In the UK, I can't find any, though that may be Google detecting my location and giving me different search results to you.

Comment: In Italy, ehem, [cellofan](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/cellofan) is the term used for *clingfilm* (or) *cling wrap*; but also that clear semi-rigid (crinkly) plastic wrapping paper that (Italian) shops use to wrap gift fruit baskets or bunches of flowers.

Comment: @oerkelens ah, "in your neck of the woods" makes much more sense; I was interpreting your comment in a general/global context :)

Comment: Just fuelling this flamewar a little more: when I first read 'cellophane tape', I thought of a kid at school, who covered his school books in the coloured, translucent polymer that Australian children called 'cellophane'. (The rest of us covered our books with 'Contact Paper'.) He used sticky tape to adhere it, and I've lived in the US long enough to think 'tape' could mean 'sticky tape'. So, with a bit of processing, 'cellophane tape' would lead me to the intended meaning. I doubt it would for that kid, though—he used 'sticky-tape' as a verb when he described his actions.

Answer (score 1):

In the US "cellophane tape" is the generic (non-trademark) term for clear sticky tape of the sort commonly used to fix paper items.

"Adhesive tape" is normally reserved for the (usually) white medical tape.

"Masking tape" is the term for a tape made from opaque paper (usually a light tan color, though often green or blue), where the tape is supposedly intended for use by painters to "mask off" areas not to be painted.

"Electrical tape" is the term for (usually black) plastic, rubber, or occasionally cloth tape of the sort intended for electrical wiring.

"Friction tape" is another term for cloth electrical tape.

"Duct tape" (more properly "duck tape") is a relatively wide (usually 2-3 inches) tape made from lightweight cloth ("duck") with a sort of thin plastic coating, with a fairly gooey adhesive.  This is an inexpensive tape commonly used for sealing packages, temporary repairs, etc.  (It, BTW, should *never* be used for sealing air ducts, or any other permanent use.)

There are, of course, other specialized tapes such as hockey tape, housewrap tape, etc.

Comment: I've never heard 'cellophane tape' before. In my experience, cellophane is *only* that clear plastic wrap used on food items, which most of my childhood acquaintances grew up calling by the brand name 'Saran wrap.' Maybe it's a regional thing.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - You must have led a deprived childhood. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid 'Scotch Tape', because I suspect many people would think you specifically mean that brand. It has properties that are sometimes specifically sought, and I've worked in offices where it's kept alongside 'regular' sticky tape, for different purposes. (Scotch Tape is less apparent, and much less likely to fade yellow, but sticky tape generally has greater tensile strength.)

(This is from my many years' living experience each in Australia and the US, and also other English-speaking countries.)